# Is it possible to make a image non-scrollable in CSS (<img src:)?

Tags: html, css

Is it in CSS to make it possible to scroll a image within a page (that isn't a background? Exactly like "background-attachment: fixed;" ?

I have tried:

```
.img {
-webkit-mask-attachment: ;
}
```

But it didn't work. I will use the image in this code snippet:

```
<div class="view view-third">
<img src="Images/bimonelle.jpg" class="image"/>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't clear enough have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to scroll the image with the page. For this, you should simply wrap your image around some div and give it the `position: fixed`.

For example, HTML:

```
<div id="advertisement">
<img src="Images/bimonelle.img" />
</div>
```

And for CSS:

```
#advertisement { position: fixed; right: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes. This was what I meant! Thanks you!